# How to vertically align inline-block elements based on a specific line, ignoring other lines?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I have several form fields, each in a parent `display: inline-block` element. Fields can have additional elements before or after the control inside them:

```css
.Field {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:gray;
}
.Control {
  color:black;
  border: solid 1px navy;
  background-color:#def;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Field">
  Some text before the line.
  <div class="Control">This</div>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  <div class="Control">should</div>
  Some text after the line.
</div>

<div class="Field">
  <div class="Control">be</div>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  Some text before...
  <div class="Control">neatly</div>
  ...and some text after. Maybe even an image.
</div>

<div class="Field">
  is it possible?
  <div class="Control">aligned</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get `vertical-align` to work such that the "main" (`.Control`) elements in the fields are next to each other.
The baseline for each `.Field` should be determined by its `.Control`.

Specifying the `line-height` manually is not an option, and the surrounding text should not have zero height or `position: absolution`: the surrounding text should still be visible, and affect the field's height.

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Another small addition - if the `Control` may also have multiple lines, and we want to align by its first line: http://jsfiddle.net/anmggL1t/1/ . Added `.Control {display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align:text-top; width:100%;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a small adjustment to your markup, putting the text after the control element into a `span` element.

Then remove the `vertical-align:middle` from the .Field div, and add `.Control + span { display:table-cell }` to hide the text after the control element from the vertical-alignment evaluation.

This gives you:

```css
.Field {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  color:gray;
}
.Control {
  color:black;
  border: solid 1px navy;
  background-color:#def;
  padding:2px;
}

.Control + span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="Field">
  Some text before the line.
  <div class="Control">This</div>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  <div class="Control">should</div>
  <span>Some text after the line.</span>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  <div class="Control">be</div>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  Some text before...
  <div class="Control">neatly</div>
  <span>...and some text after. Maybe even an image.</span>
</div>

<div class="Field">
  is it possible?
  <div class="Control">aligned</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully! I'll probably add a `span` for the text before the control too: http://jsfiddle.net/anmggL1t/ . This looks like exactly what I needed... Is there a downside to this approach? Is it valid to use `table-cell`? Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: It's definitely valid to use `table-cell` here. I guess there are downsides to *any* approach, but nothing specific springs immediately to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do with your limitations, but a sure way to do it would be using the :before and :after pseudoselectors. But that's not really maintainable as every content above or below your highlighted text should be position absolute and inside the "content" property of your CSS... Hacky stuff.

You can't achieve these kind of manipulations without absolute positioning.